# C# anonymous classes and list<object>

Tags: c#, structure

I want to access the Structures returned by a function in a List. I am not able to do it as it is causing Compiler errors.

```
public class StructTypeA
{
        public string sString1;
        public string sString2;
}
public class StructTypeB
{
        public int iNum1;
        public int iNum2;
}

public List<object> myFunction ()
{

        StructTypeA myStructA = new StructTypeA();
        StructTypeB myStructB = new StructTypeB();

        var response = new List<object> { new {oStructA = myStructA} , new {oStructB = myStructB } };

            return response;
}

public void myCallerFunction()
{
    var retVal = myFunction ();

//This does not work, it generates a compile error
// 'object' does not contain a definition for 'oStructA' and no extension method 'oStructA' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    var myStr = retVal[0].oStructA.sString1;


//How can I access the structures.
}
```

I want to access the structures oStructA and oStructB, Please tell me what the exact syntax should be.

Comment: Is your question "how to access properties of anonymous class outside the method where this class is created"?

Comment: I've updated title - feel free to revert the edit if you disagree... (No need to add thankyou notes/signature).

Comment: It's very mean to call a `class` `StructTypeA`.  It's a class, not a `struct`.  A `struct` has a very different meaning in C#.  It would be much less confusing if you called it `MyTypeA`, `MyClassA`, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Alexei and everybody else.
I am new to C# and using somebody else's code, so my confusion with names etc.
OK, What I really want is a Named class, but is there some way to instantiate it like the Anonymous object I created in the sample code.

Answer (score 4):

You're returning a `List<object>`, so `retVal[0]` is going to be of type `object`, which does not have an `oStructA` member.

You're creating a `List` that contains instances of an anonymous type. You won't be able to access those members by name outside the scope of where the type is created.

You either have to create a named type for the list:

```
class MyType
{
    public StructTypeA oStructA { get; set; }
    public StructTypeB oStructB { get; set; }
}
```

and then code your method to return a `List<MyType>`.

Creating an instance of this type is just like creating an instance of an anonymous type. Using your code example, just add the type name after **new**:

```
var response = new List<object> { new MyType {oStructA = myStructA} , new Mytype {oStructB = myStructB } };
```

Or you can use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx), and return a list of those.

Or, as somebody else said, use `dynamic`. I wouldn't recommend that in general, though. The named type is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Bonus points if the new type you create is immutable, as that's likely desirable in this case.

Comment: Thanks Jim, Yes, I think should go with the named type. Is there some method to create a Named type using the Curly braces ( Similar to the anonymous object, I created in the sample code).

Answer (score 2):

**Please, stop using the `object` type and anonymous types when not required**.

C# is a type safe language, which is the best thing that can happen to you, so **please**, use types (such as `Tuple<T1, T2>`) other than the `object` type when it's possible.

```
public List<Tuple<StructTypeA, StructTypeB>> myFunction()
{
    StructTypeA myStructA = new StructTypeA();
    StructTypeB myStructB = new StructTypeB();

    return new List<Tuple<StructTypeA, StructTypeB>> 
    {
        new Tuple<StructTypeA, StructTypeB>(myStructA, myStructB) 
    };
}

public void myCallerFunction()
{
    var retVal = myFunction();
    var oStructA = retVal[0].Item1;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't even need to be a list of tuples, he just wants to return two items, so he put them in a list.  Just return one Tuple.

Comment: @Servy I suspected that too, but I'm not really sure about that. Then name of the "myCallerFunction" doesn't help

Comment: Thanks, Yes, Servy is right, I just want to return the two objects, but am not sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think a practical reason why you'd wanna do this, but...

```
public List<dynamic> myFunction ()
{

        StructTypeA myStructA = new StructTypeA();
        StructTypeB myStructB = new StructTypeB();

        var response = new List<dynamic> { new {oStructA = myStructA} , new {oStructB = myStructB } };

            return response;
}
```

should do the trick as you are creating a list of anonymous objects.  The use of `dynamic` types may help.

Comment: While this makes the code compile, it certainly isn't the proper way of solving whatever his *actual* problem is.

Comment: his actual problem is that it's being implemented incorrectly.  my first goal is to _answer_ the question and _then_ suggest an alternative; if we're not going to answer the question this may as well be moved to code review.

Answer (score 1):

I think OP treats to do something like this:

```
public class StructTypeA
{
        public string sString1;
        public string sString2;
}
public class StructTypeB
{
        public int iNum1;
        public int iNum2;
}

public static List<object> myFunction ()
{

        StructTypeA myStructA = new StructTypeA();
        StructTypeB myStructB = new StructTypeB();

        var response = new List<object> { myStructA , myStructB };

            return response;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var retVal = myFunction ();

//This does not work, it generates a compile error
// 'object' does not contain a definition for 'oStructA' and no extension method 'oStructA' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

    var myStr1 = ((StructTypeA)retVal[0]).sString1;
    var myStr2 = ((StructTypeB)retVal[1]).iNum1;


//How can I access the structures.
}
```

***Obviously, the @Jim Mischel recommendations are very right.***

Comment: This is slightly better than what the OP had, but still fundamentally flawed.  The basic idea of using a `List` is just not appropriate in this particular context.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the grouping set up, it's not a list, but a Tuple:

```
StructTypeA myStructA = new StructTypeA();
StructTypeB myStructB = new StructTypeB();

var response = new List<object> { new {oStructA = myStructA} , new {oStructB = myStructB } };
```

A list is many items in a row. You have two items side-by-side. You could do it like this

```
List<Object> items = new List<Object>
items.Add(myStructA);
items.Add(myStructB);
```

and now both items are in a list. But having a `List<Object>` is ***always*** wrong.

You could however just put both items into a Tuple, as in:

```
Tuple<StuctTypeA, StructTypeB> resultSet = 
     new Tuple<StuctTypeA, StructTypeB>(myStructA, myStructB);
```

and just return that instead.

Comment: `But having a List<Object> is always wrong.`  It's *almost* always wrong, but it's not *always* wrong.

Comment: +0 yet... but you maybe onto an answer - OP may just want Tuple. Consider adding sample that shows that.

Answer (score 0):

You're use anonymous objects as the items in your list.  Anonymous objects are designed to be used within the scope of a single method, and not exposed to other methods.  Do so is *possible*, but difficult and creates a *lot* of problems.

Fundamentally it appears that what you're trying to do is just return two objects from your method.  You ran into the fact that you can only return one object and so you're trying to get around that.  Your instinct was to put the items into a list and return that.  You further decided to put the objects inside of an anonymous object before putting them into a list.  To address this issue using more standard coding conventions we need to back *way* out.  You shouldn't be using a `List` in this context in the first place.

You want to create some type that can hold onto those two objects; it should have two properties, one for each object.  You could make your own if you wanted, if there is a logical "type" that represents these two structures.  If that doesn't really make sense, and you don't think that's really worth the effort in this context you can just use an existing general purpose holder called `Tuple`.

```
public Tuple<StructTypeA, StructTypeB> myFunction()
{
    StructTypeA myStructA = new StructTypeA();
    StructTypeB myStructB = new StructTypeB();

    return Tuple.Create(myStructA , myStructB);
}
```

Now from the caller's perspective we know that we're getting back a `Tuple` that has two items, the first is of type `StructTypeA`, and the second is of type `StructTypeB`.

```
var returnValues = myFunction();
var myStr = returnValues.Item1.sString1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var structA = retVal.OfType<StructTypeA>().First();
var myStr = structA.sString1;
```

Remember to include a

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: How would this work? `retVal` contains a list of anonymous objects [which have no type] that have a member of type `StuctTypeA`.  So `OfType` would not work

Comment: -1 - you can't do this cast - items inside the list are of anonymous class which in turn contains 2 other classes as fields.